# which is best practise on importing a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Most of the times i import a module like below.

```
import * as fs from "fs"

const Reporter = {
    createDirectory: (dir) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            mkdirp.sync(dir)
        }
    }
}
```

But I see some developers/tutorials import modules inside the function calls or only on the required methods as below.

```
const Reporter = {
    import * as fs from "fs"

    createDirectory: (dir) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            mkdirp.sync(dir)
        }
    }
}
```

1. Which is the best practice?
2. What is advantages/disadvantages of using in both ways?

Comment: The second is not valid ES6 syntax. Where exactly did you find that?

Comment: its my bad. instead of copying vanilla javascript project code, i accidentally copied the code from my another es6 project and manually put the import statement. but what i meant to ask was same about static and dynamic import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way (inside the declaration of `Reporter`) is incorrect syntax.

Static import statements always have to be at the top of the module.

Perhaps you're confusing static with dynamic imports. A dynamic import would be OK inside the variable declaration and would look like this, for example:

```
const Reporter = {
    createDirectory: (dir) => {
        import("fs").then(fs => {
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
                mkdirp.sync(dir)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The advantage of using dynamic modules is that you can use tools like webpack to do [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), i.e. optimize the size of your initial javascript bundle to the code that is needed when the page is first rendered. Dynamic imports are loaded asynchronously from other bundles only when needed.

If you don't use code splitting, the static imports are the recommended way to go, according to the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: Ok. i get you. Is there any benefits in using the dynamic import over static?

Comment: You can use tools like webpack to do code splitting,i.e. optimize the size of your initial javascript bundle to the code that is needed when the page is first rendered. Dynamic imports are loaded asynchronously from other bundles only when needed

Comment: sorry i still find it hard to get it. i understand the dynamic import loaded async. but which is the best option, for example performance wise?

Comment: Of you don't use code splitting, the static imports are the recommended way to go, according to Mozilla Developer Network  documentation